# Redirect logging from an external method in java

Tags: java, logging

I have a use-case where 2 java processes are long running, already instantiated objects, and one object calls a method on another.

Java process1 calls a ".execute" on java process2, and runs it in a separate thread. Is there a way to redirect the stdOut of that specific execute method in java process2 - such that process1 can fetch and render that std out as logs?
Process2 is an external system, and I wouldn't want to change the code of the external system.

Comment: Is process2 running in a separate thread or in a separate process?

Comment: It's running as a separate thread

Answer (score 0):

The nature of System.out is that it is the same for the entire jvm. It is not possible for different Threads to have a reference to a different System.out. So you can redirect System.out for the entire jvm to logs, but not just a single Thread.